# Where is the first marble skin in Super Blocky Ball's lobby?

Tags: roblox

The other four heads are relatively easy to find (atop the castle crenelations) but where is the first of the five skins in the lobby? I have a sinking feeling that it's in some impossible location like atop the loop-the-loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. The cyan head is hidden in the corner nearest the Glass Houses sign, atop the crenelations.